# What is E in floating point?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, scientific-notation

What is *E+3*? What exactly happens here? Can we use this approach in other data types or can we only use it in floating point numbers?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double w = 1.7E+3;
    Console.WriteLine(w);
}
```

Output: 1700

Comment: The answers you will get for the various languages will be similar, but not identical. Please choose **one** programming language and limit your question to it.

Comment: E+3 == 10^3 == 10*10*10 == 1000. Thus, 1.7 * 1000 = 1700. It's called "engineering notation" afaik

Comment: I wonder why would anybody prefer 1.7E+3 compared to just 1700.

Comment: @Rob: I don't know about asp, but for all the other languages he's chosen, the answer is in fact identical.

Comment: @BlueM - Because for much larger or smaller numbers it is more compact, e.g., 1.7E+30 is easier than typing or reading the 29 zeros in 1700000000000000000000000000000. (And if you know you'll be dealing with a range of large numbers it is often easier to stick to the one notation style. I wouldn't use E notation if I knew all the numbers I needed were only up to four or five digits.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> [E notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)
>
> Most calculators and many computer programs present very large and very small results in scientific notation. Because superscripted exponents like 10<sup>7</sup> cannot always be conveniently displayed, the letter E or e is often used to represent times ten raised to the power of (which would be written as "x 10<sup>b</sup>") and is followed by the value of the exponent. Note that in this usage the character e is not related to the mathematical constant *e* or the exponential function *e<sup>x</sup>* (a confusion that is less likely with capital E); and though it stands for exponent, the notation is usually referred to as (scientific) E notation or (scientific) e notation, rather than (scientific) exponential notation (though the latter also occurs). The use of this notation is not encouraged by publications.

---

As for your second question:

> can we use this approach in other data type or we can only use it in floating points?

See the [C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691085(v=vs.71).aspx):

> Real literals [the type of numeric literals that are allowed an `E` in them] are used to write values of types `float`, `double`, and `decimal`.

However, you have to cast or suffix the literal appropriately when assigning to anyhting other than a `Double`, because any literal with an `e` or `E` in it is recognized as a `Double` in Visual Studio. I cannot find where this behavior is specified.

```
float f1 = 7E1;     // Compile error. Needs F suffix (7E1F)
decimal d1 = 8E2;   // Compile error. Needs M suffix (8E2M)
double d2 = 9E3;    // Works.

int overninethousand = (int)9E3 + 1; // Works
```

Answer (score 19):

In general, that's [exponential/scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)...

1.7E+3 = 1.7 x 10<sup>3</sup> = 1700

Answer (score 7):

E+3 means the decimal place is moved 3 times to the right

1.7 -> 17.0 -> 170.0 -> 1700.0

Answer (score 3):

E+3 = 10<sup>3</sup>, so 1.7 · 10<sup>3</sup> = 1700