# Understanding pocketsphinx keyword list file format

Tags: android, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I'm testing an app based on the demo avaialble on GitHub using the Spanish language model in which I want it to continuously listen for a small set of keywords and act accordingly, however I'm still an amateur on this subject. My main questions right now are the following:

Given my current **setupRecognizer** method

```
private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {

    recognizer = SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "es-ptm"))
            .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "es.dict"))
            .setRawLogDir(assetsDir)
            .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);

    File actionGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "actions.list");
    recognizer.addKeywordSearch(SEARCH, actionGrammar);

    File languageModel = new File(assetsDir, "es_model.lm");
    recognizer.addNgramSearch(SEARCH, languageModel);

    startSearch(SEARCH);
}
```

What happens by adding both **addKeywordSearch** and **addNGramSearch**, under the same identifier string ("SEARCH" in my code)? Am I improving the recognition or making it worse?

In a desperate attempt, I reduced the dictionary to only the words I want to be recognized, such as this:

```
atrás a t r a s 
listo l i s t o 
listo(2) l i s t a
listo(3) l i s t a s
listos(4) l i s t o s
repetir rr e p e t i r
repetir(2) rr e p e t i d o
repetirse(3) rr e p e t i r s e
```

It is now reduced to only recognizing these words, but it misbehaves a lot, identifying words I didn't say. I'm guessing PocketSphinx is probability-based and since I reduced the dictionary these words have high probability of being recognized. Am I correct?

Also in an attempt to improve my accuracy, I made this **actions.list**

```
listo /1.0/
atrás /1.0/
repetir /1.0/
```

Although I'm not really sure what this value means. It says on the documentation to use 1e-1 for smaller words, and **increase** to 1e-50 for bigger words. What notation is this and what does it mean?

I'm really concerned about making it as accurate as possible, am I on the right path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> What happens by adding both addKeywordSearch and addNGramSearch, under the same identifier string ("SEARCH" in my code)?

The ngram search replaces keyword search, keyword search is garbage collected

> What notation is this

[What is E in floating point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687016/what-is-e-in-floating-point)

Comment: Hm, ok, Thanks for clarifying! How does the threshold affect the detection process? The time it takes to spell the word?

Comment: Threshold affects the results, not the process or the time. Different threshold gives different amount of detection results.